# create the list without reset the list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need some help with my code. I'm creating the list to store the values in the list without reset the list.

When I try this:

```
for channel in channels:
    program_remaining = list()

    if current_time == start_time:
       print "the program has started"

    elif start_time != current_time < stop_time:
        print "program is half way"
        current_time = datetime.timedelta(hours = get_24_hours, minutes = get_24_minutes)
        end_program = datetime.timedelta(hours = int(program_hours), minutes = int(program_minutes))
        current_program = end_program - current_time
        test = int(current_program.seconds / 60)
    program_remaining.append(test)
    print "program_remaining"
    print program_remaining
```

I will get the output like this:

```
19:17:30 T:1872  NOTICE: [13]
19:17:30 T:1872  NOTICE: [43]
19:17:30 T:1872  NOTICE: [13]
19:17:30 T:1872  NOTICE: [43]
19:17:30 T:1872  NOTICE: [13]
19:17:30 T:1872  NOTICE: [13]
19:17:30 T:1872  NOTICE: [43]
```

It should be look like this:

```
[13]
[13, 43]
[13, 43, 13]
[13, 43, 13, 43]
[13, 43, 13, 43, 13]
[13, 43, 13, 43, 13, 13]
[13, 43, 13, 43, 13, 43]
```

It will keep reset the list everytime when I added the values in the list and it will keep wipe out what it was previously added.

Can you show me how I can store the values in the list without reset the list under the for channel loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create the list outside the loop

```
program_remaining = list()
for channel in channels:
    if current_time == start_time:
       print "the program has started"

    elif start_time != current_time < stop_time:
        print "program is half way"
        current_time = datetime.timedelta(hours = get_24_hours, minutes = get_24_minutes)
        end_program = datetime.timedelta(hours = int(program_hours), minutes = int(program_minutes))
        current_program = end_program - current_time
        test = int(current_program.seconds / 60)
    program_remaining.append(test)
    print "program_remaining"
    print program_remaining
```

That way the list will not get initialized to an empty list at every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the list outside the `for`

Change:

```
for channel in channels:
    program_remaining = list()
    ...
```

with:

```
program_remaining = list()
for channel in channels:
    ...
```